# unable to start psql : no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1" , user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I am unable to connect using `psql` to PostgreSQL 9.6 on Windows 10. I saw almost all the StackExchange questions regarding this error. While installing Postgres it asked for superuser password and I set it. Added `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` and  `host all all ::0/0 trust` to `pg_hba.conf` but still no luck. This is the `pg_hba.conf` contents on my machine:

```
host    all             all             localhost               trust

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

host    all             all             ::0/0                   trust

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show how exactly you are attempting to connect (I mean the command line)?  The server and the client are on the same machine, IIUC.

Comment: ```psql  -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres``` i tried to give this

Comment: Please look at the server log and search for the line where it confirms that the file is correctly reloaded.

Comment: I have very little experience with databases on Windows, but I remember that the loopback adapter had to be "installed" or activated, it didn't exist by default.   If you check your hosts file, do you find "127.0.0.1 localhost"?  Another possibilty is your server is listening on IPv6 only.

Comment: Quoting "https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html" : `The pg_hba.conf file is read on start-up and when the main server process receives a SIGHUP signal. If you edit the file on an active system, you will need to signal the postmaster (using pg_ctl reload or kill -HUP) to make it re-read the file.`   Did you restart?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did , I have no idea why it worked but it may help you lol.

The error message is something like :

FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host “fe70::3069:d1cc:6120:27e5%15” ...bla..bla

I don't even know much about IP6 but I assume that long weird number is my ip6, so I added it to my pg_hba.conf

```
  host    all             all             fe70::3069:d1cc:6120:27e5/96  trust
```

That /96 is what I took from the manual. I can care less about what it mean since it is dev env. and ABOVE ALL it works on my

Answer (score 0):

Per your configuration,  you are exposing all the IPs to your database which is not recommended.

Please reload the config file using  /usr/edb/bin/pg_ctl -D /datadirectorypath  reload

Post reload,  you may try to connect again.